# Crear un for para consultar valores de un data

Tags: r, loops

Tengo un data con varias variables y quiero usar un for para que recorra varias variables y consulte los valores.

El data table datos contiene las variables V1, V2... V15. Lo que quiero es crear una variable Stotal que sea la suma de los valores SI que hay en las variables V1 a V15.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(datos)){
for (j in 1:15){
   (if(sprintf("V%d",j)[i])=="SI"){
aux<-1
Stotal[i]<-1+aux
}
}
```

El codigo no funciona, entre otras cosas, porque la función sprintf pega el texto pero no saca el valor de la variable en la posicion que le pido.

**Editado:**
Un ejemplo con menos columnas podría ser:

```
V1 <- c("Si","No","Si")
V2 <- c("Si","No","No")
V3<-c("Si","Si","Si")

datos <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
datos
  V1 V2 V3
1 Si Si Si
2 No No Si
3 Si No Si
```

En este caso la salida esperada sería: `3 1 2`

Comment: ¿Puede dar un ejemplo del "data table tablos" por favor ?

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilisar una dataframe :

```
Sval<-0   
# Creo tres vectores of misma tamano. Utiliso tres vectores para simplicidad
V1 <- c(5,9,3)
V2 <- c(10,11,12)
V3<-c(13,14,15)
X <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)    
rownames(X) <- c("SI","b","c")
datos <- X    
print(datos)
```

Que da :

> ```
>    V1 V2 V3
> SI  5 10 13
> b   9 11 14
> c   3 12 15
> ```

Y para calcular las valores del attributo SI :

```
for (val in datos["SI",]){
    Stotal=Stotal + val
}

print(Stotal)
```

Que da

> `[1] 28`

Answer (score 0):

Más allá que lo puedas resolver mediante un `loop` R tiene mecanismos más efectivos y performantes. Por ejemplo:

```
V1 <- c("Si","No","Si")
V2 <- c("Si","No","No")
V3<-c("Si","Si","Si")

datos <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
datos
apply(datos, MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(ifelse(x=="Si", 1, 0)))
```

La Salida:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1 Si Si Si
2 No No Si
3 Si No Si

V1 V2 V3 
 2  1  3
```

- Aplicamos [`apply()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) la función [`sum`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) a `datos` por fila`MARGIN = 1`
- Pero solo sumamos 1 si el valor es `Si` (`ifelse(x=="Si", 1, 0)`)

O incluso mucho más fácil:

```
rowSums(datos[,]=="Si")
```

- Aplicamos [`rowSums`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) para sumar por fila, únicamente los valores que sean `Si` (`datos[,]=="Si"`)

Comment: Con rowSums de lujo.
Muchas gracias!
Que facil... que mala es la ignorancia